# Conditional Calculations

Tags: cognito-forms

I am trying to build a building permit form that calculates the fee based on the cost of the project.  I created a box called "Project Cost" and "Fee Cost".  We have ranges for the fee, not a fixed percentage.

For instance, 0-$500=$24.68, $501.00-$600=$29.27, $601-$700=$31.08 etc.  My goal is if someone types in $50 in the project cost, $24.68 gets auto populated in the "Fee Cost" area, as we are going to take credit card payments based on the "Fee Cost" amount.

Every time I try and build something using some of the other examples on this post I get an error message.

Comment: What sort of error message? Please [edit] your question to include this important information.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an if-then calculations in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) to handle this like follows:

`=if ProjectCost <= 500 then 24.68 
else if ProjectCost <= 600 then 29.27 
else if ProjectCost <= 700 then 31.08 
else 50`

You can add as many "else if" items on to this to accommodate additional ranges. The 50 at the end in this example is just the catch-all for projects higher than the final range. Put this calculation into the Amount field for your Price field to include it on your invoice.